# IIS 7 rewrite for subfolders

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup some rewrite rules for sub folders.

**Example**

Redirect the following

- /somefolder
- /somefolder/

to

- /somefolder/default.aspx

> ```
> <rewrite>
>             <rules>
>                 <rule name="Some Folder">
>                     <match url="^/somefolder$" />
>                     <action type="Rewrite" url="/Somefolder/default.aspx" />
>                 </rule>
>             </rules>
>         </rewrite>
> ```

Comment: are you getting an error? what problems are you having?